# Associating route 53 Nameservers with GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, godaddy, amazon-route53

I am using GoDaddy as domain, & AWS for instances. I have created route 53, & it generated four DNS. should I replace the two default GoDaddy DNS with route 53? or I add four AWS DNS & also keep two DNS of GoDaddy?

how can I prevent Downtime with Fail-safe settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to replace the two GoDaddy nameservers with the four Route53 ones.

To prevent downtime, ensure you have the same records in both GoDaddy and Route53 before making the nameserver changes.

Comment: I added all four AWS ns to GoDaddy and my domain doesn't load anymore (down for 3 hours now). Does it take time for ns to get implemented?

Comment: @Pratik Did you make sure you had the same records in both? What's the domain name so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is best, you can also add route 53 as slave zone and do a zone transfer (Premium DNS Only)

Godaddy also has a zone export option.