# Can Route 53 nameservers be added to GoDaddy?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, amazon-route53

Recently, I had a requirement of adding Route 53 nameservers to GoDaddy. I replaced the 2 default GoDaddy nameservers with the 4 Route 53 ones. This made a lot of functionalities of my site go down. I did not have the same records in both Route 53 and GoDaddy.

I understand from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/721221/344691) that I should have the same records in both. But why is it required? If the nameservers are added to GoDaddy, then isn't the nameserver supposed to pick up the DNS Zone file from GoDaddy also?

Comment: If your domain's nameservers are set to Route53, all of your records must be in Route53 - any set in GoDaddy will be ignored. If they're set to GoDaddy, all of your records must be in GoDaddy - any set in Route53 will be ignored. The two sets of nameservers do *not* communicate in any way with each other.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're also using GoDaddy for hosting, you may (in some cases) be obliged to use GoDaddy's nameservers for your hosting to work. Their shared hosting can see IP changes - GoDaddy will manage them in their nameservers, but if you're using Route53 you have to manually maintain the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your nameservers as Route53, then the only thing anybody is going to ask GoDaddy for is the reference to your Route53 nameservers. I think you are assuming that Route53 will do a 'zone transfer' from Godaddy and pick up all the existing records, but this is not the case. AWS does not offer 'slave' nameservers, only authoritative nameservers.